# Matrix analysis , inequalities , diagonal entries

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Suppose we have an invertible positive definite matrix and we know its diagonal elements when seen as a vector are in increasing order , what can be said about  diagonal vector of its inverse ? , if it's in increasing order or decreasing order etc

Answer (score 0):

No:

for example

$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 5 
\end{pmatrix}$

has an inverse where the diagonal elements are not in order

$\begin{pmatrix}
\;\;\frac{11}{30} & -\frac1{15} & -\frac{1}{30}\\
-\frac1{15} & \;\;\frac{14}{30} & -\frac4{15}  \\
-\frac{1}{30} & -\frac4{15} & \;\;\frac{11}{30} 
\end{pmatrix}$